# How do I set the headers to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" on a XML based API Call

Tags: php, xml, api

I am looking over the documentation for the VerMail API and they specify that I need to set the headers to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but I have to send the data as XML.. I know this is automatic if I send the data in an array but how would I do it with XML?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
$xmlcontent = "
<api>
  <authentication>
    <api_key>".$apiKey."</api_key>
    <shared_secret>".$apiSecret."</shared_secret>
    <response_type>xml</response_type>
  </authentication>

  <data>
    <methodCall>
      <methodname>legacy.message_stats</methodname>
      <last>100</last>
    </methodCall>
  </data>
</api>
";

$xmlcontent = urlencode($xmlcontent);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=".$xmlcontent);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($content);
```

This is what I see on the source code when I run it:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Jan 2015 20:17:52 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: max-age=18000
Expires: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 01:17:52 GMT
Content-Length: 595
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerBH-gen-80=235023882.20480.0000; path=/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodResponse><item><error><![CDATA[1]]></error><responseText><![CDATA[ XML Error: Please verify the XML request is valid.  For special characters please ensure you are using <![CDATA[ ]]]]><![CDATA[> blocks and url encoding data properly.]]></responseText><responseData><error><![CDATA[Not well-formed (invalid token) at line: 1]]></error><responseCode><![CDATA[425]]></responseCode></responseData><responseNum><![CDATA[1]]></responseNum><totalRequests><![CDATA[0]]></totalRequests><totalCompleted><![CDATA[0]]></totalCompleted></item></methodResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the headers manually so you can specify that you are sending and want back XML

You should not have to URLencode the xml.

Also the postfields should be just the XML.  not XML=$xmlcontent

```
$xmlcontent = "
<api>
  <authentication>
    <api_key>".$apiKey."</api_key>
    <shared_secret>".$apiSecret."</shared_secret>
    <response_type>xml</response_type>
  </authentication>

  <data>
    <methodCall>
      <methodname>legacy.message_stats</methodname>
      <last>100</last>
    </methodCall>
  </data>
</api>
";

$xmlcontent = urlencode($xmlcontent);

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array(
                "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                "Accept: text/xml",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Pragma: no-cache",
                "Content-length: ".strlen($xmlcontent),
            );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlcontent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```